# TextView will not update from a loop in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, textview

I have a simple app that updates a `TextView` from a values generated in a loop when i click on a button.

But when i run the app, it only shows the last number in the `TextView`. I added a `Thread.sleep()` to slow down the loop but it did not work, Still the same result. What am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advace

```java
public class MainThread extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btnShow;
    TextView txtSee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_thread);

        btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        txtSee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSee);

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

                        String text1 = "Iteration No " + i + " occured";
                        txtSee.setText(text1);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: `onClick` is called in the UI thread. You should ***NEVER*** call `Thread.sleep()` in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 txtSee.append(text1);
```

instead of

```
 txtSee.setText(text1);
```

your loop is executing too fast to let you observe the changes

Comment: did not work, all the appended text showed up at the end of the loop.

Comment: this is because you have sleep your thread for 2 seconds and in between of that the loop executes

Answer (score 0):

Call another function inside loop and use 
        `txtSee.setText(text1);` inside that function.

```
               or (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

                            String text1 = "Iteration No " + i + " occured";
                            call_function(text1,txtSee);

                        }
```

call_function:-

```
call_function(String text1,TextView txtSee;){
                      txtSee.setText(text1);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                       }
```

Comment: I don't see why the OP would need to move the code in a subroutine like this to solve his problem. Although this might be a good practice, it shouldn't be presented as part of the solution. Also, you call `setText()` in your subroutine instead of the `append` method you're talking about.

Comment: @Joffrey, Because `append` is method to add the coming things without deleting previous one and here he needs to show the text for 2 seconds only. That's why i used it.

Comment: I didn't say `append()` was the right thing to do, but that's what you say in your intro text, and you don't do it in the code.

Comment: @Joffrey, Thanku bro for pointing this.I didn't see . my mistake. Now i have edited my answer..